# Compiling and running JUnit in command line

Tags: java, json, junit

I have a project done in Java and we cannot use the IDE to compile it and run it, we are only allowed to use the command line. This project uses JSON. I have managed to successfully compiled and run it as follows:

Compile: javac -cp ./lib/java-json.jar ./src/project/*.java

Run: java -cp ./bin:./lib/java-json.jar project.Main

Now my next step is to run a JUnit test in the command line. To compile I tried:

javac [source files] -cp "path-to-JUnit-jar-files" path-to-JUnit-class

which looks like this:

javac ./src/project/*.java -cp "./lib/JUnit/*.jar" ./src/testing/AllTests.java

This is the closest I have gotten to successfully compiling the unit test class (I think) because it gave me only a few errors in comparison to other commands I have tried. The errors it gave me are that it needs the classpath to the JSON jar file, but I don't know how to tell the command line to do that.

Comment: I presume you are also not permitted to use Maven or Gradle? (This is the way that Real Projects are compiled, and they're used from the command line so that they can be run on build servers.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I can use Maven or Gradle, I have never used this though. If I decide to learn how to do it using Maven, will I need to re-create the entire project as a Maven project to be able to use the mvn clean test? I already pushed what I have to github. Can I just "apply" maven to my current project?

Comment: You don't have to rewrite your project, just move the files into the Standard Directory Layout (basically, `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`).